# RegEx for matching several occurrences after lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I got following passage in a text file:

```
(default) AA / BBB)
ASDF / XYZ / GE
(default) CCCC)
```

I want to match all uppercase letters (2-4) after `(default)` to the closing bracket, so `AA`, `BBB` and `CCCC` are matched.

This is what i came up with, but it doesn't match the `BBB`:

```
(?<=default\)\s)[A-Z]{2,4}
```

So what am I missing to match more than one group of uppercase letters after `(default)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we wish to only match the pattern in the question, we would just simply pass our desired cases and fail the other one using `(default)`:

```
\(default\)(.+?([A-Z]{2,4}).+?([A-Z]{2,4})|.+?([A-Z]{2,4}))
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/WUG2UO/1/)

or:

```
(?=\(default\))(.+?([A-Z]{2,4}).+?([A-Z]{2,4})|.+?([A-Z]{2,4})).+
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/PTtSfy/1/)

```js
const regex = /\(default\)(.+?([A-Z]{2,4}).+?([A-Z]{2,4})|.+?([A-Z]{2,4}))/gm;
const str = `(default) AA / BBB)
ASDF / XYZ / GE
(default) CCCC)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution.